# *ngIf multidimensional array Angular2

Tags: angular

I have created an array to call it from the template in Angular 2

```
    books: any[] = [{
        name: "The Name book",
        chapter: [{
            name: 'Alpha',
            pages: '180'
        }, {
            name: 'Beta',
            pages: '100'
        }]
    }]
```

So, in the template, I would like to call it like this

```
    <li *ngFor="#book of books" >
            {{book.chapter.name}}
    </li>
```

But it doesn't work, any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `chapter` property is an array, so you have to pass it to `ngFor` also.

```
<template ngFor [ngForOf]="books" let-book>
     <li *ngFor="let chapter of book.chapter">
        {{chapter.name}}
     </li>
</template>
```

[Check this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/IsDYJPiu6oaAzvvla5hL?p=preview)

Please notice that I am using the `let-book` syntax since the `#book` syntax is deprecated.